# Select method with args separated by double-pipes only checking first element... Alternative?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a bit of broken legacy code I have to fix. Its purpose was to take a large array and return elements that have a particular sector number.

Here's a simplified version of the code in the app. Goal: return any instance of 1 or 3 in array:

```
array = [1,1,2,2,3,3].select{|num| num == (1 || 3) }
```

But the return value is simply `#=> [1, 1]` when the desired return was `#=> [1, 1, 3, 3]`

Basically, what I'm looking for is the Ruby equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT num FROM array
WHERE num IN (1, 3);
```

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below to meet your need :

```
array = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
array.select{|num| [1,3].include? num }
# => [1, 1, 3, 3]
```

See why you got only `[1,1]`.

```
1 || 3 # => 1
```

`1 || 3` will always returns `1`, thus `num == 1` is evaluated as true when select is passing only `1`. As a result you got `[1,1]`.